# Stream synchronization in c++

Tags: c++, stream, synchronization

I've recently taken test about C++. It is already finished, but I only know my score and do not know correct answers. There were two questions:

**1. Can C++ streams be synchronized using functions from standard? (yes or no)**

**2. Can C++ stream be synchronized with stdio input/output using functions from standard? (yes or no)**

I don't know answer to first question. The answer to the second question is yes, because we have function `ios_base::sync_with_stdio()`.

There was no context in test, and it was 'general c++ knowledge test'. So I cannot guess context. Though it was abou C++03 standard, so multithreaded sunchronization is out, I think.

What are correct answers?
Thank you.

Comment: Yes, with [`basic_ios::tie()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/tie)

Comment: It is, at least, unclear what that question refers to! I would guess along the lines of 0x499602D2 but without context from the course it is unclear whether synchronization refers to between input and output (with the answer being "yes" using `std::basic_ios<...>::tie()`), between the external and the internal representation (with the anwer being "yes" using `std::ios_base::unitbuf`), or between threads (with the answer being "no, not really").

Comment: @DietmarKühl, even for the third variant, they can be synchronized using std::mutex, for instance. Depends on the meaning of synchronized.

Comment: _@DoctorMoisha_ Sorry, I have to infer unclearness of the tests question into your's here. It's not a general yes/no question, but requires more context.

Comment: The test had no context. Though it was about C++03 standard, so I think multithreaded synchronization is out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Can C++ streams be synchronized using functions from standard? (yes or no)

Yes, they can using  [tie()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/tie/). The tied stream is an output stream object which is flushed before each I/O operation in this stream object.

> 2. Can C++ stream be synchronized with stdio input/output using functions from standard? (yes or no)

Yes, they can by buffer manipulation, using single buffer with both streams, using [rdbuf()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/rdbuf/) (and [sync()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/sync/)).

Answer (score 0):

c++20 adds new functionality for output stream synchronization:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_osyncstream